# How do i write a long book monologue?

Tags: fiction, creative-writing, dialogue

There is a point in a book I'm writing where a character relates a lengthy story about the inner struggles that she faced a couple years ago. Wouldn't it look a bit awkward if the entire thing was just one ginormous paragraph that opened and closed with quotation marks? It just seems unnatural, especially for a book. Is it possible to write a long monologue like that without the above issue?

Comment: Browse the Internet for the John Galt monologue (written in the form of a radio speech) form Ayn Rand's "Atlas Shrugged." You don't need to read it, just take not of its length. That's a famous book, for better or worse.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to write a long monologue without it being awkward. Just because something is one long statement from a single character does not mean that it all has to be in one paragraph. You can separate ideas in the monologue (or organic pauses in speaking or however you want to do it) into multiple paragraphs; just

1. **Do not** close the paragraphs with quotation marks (until the monologue is finished)
2. **Do** begin every paragraph with quotation marks.

See [this article](http://baxtercommunications.nl/quotation-marks-multi-paragraph-rule/) and [these](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/2288/74434) questions [from English Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/96608/74434) for more information.

Comment: This is very important. Make it organic. A person will not just sit perfectly still and recount something. They will move around, pause, gather their thoughts, clear the throat, have a sip of water or whatever else. Bring that movement into it

Comment: Right. And if it were long enough, you could break the quotation mark train and make that movement explicit.